# Store a specific hour but in datetime type SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table that have two columns, one is called HourFrom and HourTo, this hours can be changed. I dont want the type to be `nvarchar` the only thing that needs to store is for example 08:00 or 23:00.

Is there a way to design the table with functions that only shows the hour instead of creating (for example) a Store Procedure that saves the datetime with this functions?

The reason behind this is because I have an entity in my backend where these two members are `Datetime` as they should be and dont want to mix types and doing weird castings or using `split`,`indexOf`, etc.

Comment: You can use the time datatype.

Comment: Question is a bit murky, there is the TIME type, or of course any of the int types.

Comment: So you want to store as a datetime but when you query have it formatted to just show the time?

Comment: I suggest changing those columns to something like tinyint(2) unsigned, or whatever the equivalent is in your database (this was a MySQL example)

Comment: For the person who downvoted, please give an explanation so I can improve how Im making the question.
Thanks!

Comment: @SeanLange
Sean, I changed it to time(4) and made an insert, the value is stored as 08:00:00.0000 instead of 08:00, How can I parse the seconds and miliseconds?

Comment: If you want a certain format you need to do this when the data is retrieved.

Comment: @SeanLange Ok, so when I called the SP that retrieves the data I can parse it there. 
Thanks,

Comment: Why you don't use two datetime columns so u can do anything to them without problems?

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani that is a good question and my answer would be that I dont want to deal with days or months or years, just hours and minutes and I dont see apropiate to use int and concatenate a : in my codebehind, for me, if something is of type date, datetime or time in your Database it must be the same type on the other end (same backwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use time(0), data may look like 03:06:12, 08:45:00. I have no idea how you going to use the data. Eg, if in where clause, where HourFrom between '03:00:00' and '04:00:00', does it matter if HourFrom contains minute and second?